# Laravel Homestead: Nginx failing to start on Vagrant. Need root password to access Nginx logs

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel Homestead to work with Laravel 4. After running *vagrant up* this morning, I was unable to access homestead.app:8000. I pinged it with no problem so I investigated my virtualbox and discovered that Nginx wasn't starting. I then attempted to view logs and I am denied permission from the /var/log/nginx directory which is owned by **www-data  adm**.

My question then, what is the **su** or **sudo** password which would allow me to access that directory? The documentation is surprisingly void of any information as well as the Homestead.app Git repository. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick way to jump to a root account shell is to run the "sudo bash" command.  That way, if you don't have to have to type "sudo" in front of each command.  Since this VM is for development purposes I don't see it as a danger, but in real production Ubuntu runs with the root account locked down so you always go in and should stay in with user level privileges until you need to execute a higher level command.  You "can" enable the root account and set a password, but jumping to it with sudo is the better method.

Answer (score 10):

i had similar issue with `laravel/homestead` vagrant virtual machine and `nginx` not restarting. the error after running `nginx -t` was :

```
nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sites-available" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

solution was to delete the symbolic link `sites_available`:

```
rm -Rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sites-available
```

than it worked:
`service nginx restart`

Comment: This worked for me, except i had a node_modules instead of sites-avaiable causing the problem. I think it was from cassandra installation. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

elevate to root by typing sudo -s

Answer (score 0):

You can just look at the log using the `root` account password. So: sudo nano  and then just enter your `root` user's password. A root is able to do anything on the system, so that always is a solution for this kind of problems.

If you forgot the root password, just search google to recover it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. In this case it is a pre-built and standardized virtual machine provided by laravel.com which thousands of developers use. It has predefined passwords for other services (e.g. MySQL) but they don't provide root credentials for some reason.

Comment: @deeperDATA Didnt know laravel provides this kind of things!