# What is Vagrant Homestead root password?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have installed Homestead with

vagrant box add laravel/homestead
vagrant init
vagrant up

I can login with user vagrant:vagrant, but I can't login as root!

root:root and root:vagrant is wrong password.

I have solution: there is no root password, because user "vagrant" can run sudo -s bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Homestead: Nginx failing to start on Vagrant. Need root password to access Nginx logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368281/laravel-homestead-nginx-failing-to-start-on-vagrant-need-root-password-to-acce)

Answer (score 16):

For me, I was able to type `sudo su` and then I became `root`.

See https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/root-password-for-homestead-not-mysql-root-password/replies/107601 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28097781/470749

Comment: First link is broken: ` You have ventured into 404 space. (Page Not Found)`

Comment: @Pathros Thanks. That's why I wrote the answer first rather than just pasting a link. But I wanted to give credit to how I learned it.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base#vagrant-user), the *vagrant* user default password is just `vagrant`.

> This user should be setup with the insecure keypair that **Vagrant** uses as a default to attempt to SSH. Also, even though **Vagrant** uses key-based authentication by default, it is a general convention to set the **password** for the "**vagrant**" user to "**vagrant**". This lets people login as that user manually if they need to.

Comment: Please use text instead of picture

Comment: This was the correct answer for Homestead 12.x.

Answer (score 1):

The username and password for both databases is homestead / secret.
Follow the section "Connecting to Databases" at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#connecting-to-databases

Comment: This is not accurate in my experience. The output when restarting PHP states the username is vagrant, and I've tried password 'secret' and it's not accepted. Maybe this was version specific? It is true for databases, but not the service / ssh itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this password: secret

I think that password works.

Comment: No, it is not! System is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS homestead

Comment: It is for homestead mysql: root/secret.

Comment: in windows homestead it works... woked for fee... thanks

Comment: `$ su`  Password: `secret`. Then I got `su: Authentication failure`

Answer (score 0):

Ive come to a solution by changing the port:
DB_PORT=33060 in the .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```